# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: Elog

Tags: architecture, xcode5

In my prefix.pch file :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

But when archiving i am getting this error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define `DEBUG_MODE`.

I updated to the following and it works

## define DEBUG_MODE

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```